# Best way to use middleware Auth in Laravel to redirect

Tags: laravel

So I'm upgrading a project from Laravel 5.0 to 5.4 and I've just stumble across the method now depreciated `beforeFilter` which was used this way :

```
function __construct() {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('only'=>array('showDashboard')));
}
```

Which basically say (from my understanding) if you'r not logged in yet you can still use the method `showDashBoard`.

So I'm trying to do something similar.

I've tried `$this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['showDashboard']]);` but without success.

I tough of extracting the middleware from the construct and putting it directly in the routes but this not seems to be a clean solution for me.

Comment: what exactly happens? the middleware doesnt apply the `except`? or doesn't work at all?

Comment: "Too many redirection" my guess is the auth middleware is redirecting to this precise controler; etc etc

Comment: what is your route for `showDashboard`? do you redirect to `showDashboard` when a user is not authenticated?

Comment: `showDashboard` is a method of the controller of this construct.

Comment: yeah, but what is the route for accessing that method?

Comment: Are you using the auth middleware somewhere else that will affect this controller e.g. a `Route::group`?